# Linq Dynamic Query OrderBy With Navigation Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this method bellow to build a dynamic linq query with pagination and sort. But when a send to sort by a property that has relation with other entity like Entity Product has relation with Customer and a call the method to get Customer and in "includeProperties" send Product and i want sort by "Product.Name". it didn't works

The Method:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "", int page = 0, int pagesize = 100, string sortColumn = "", string sortColumnDir = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (sortColumn != string.Empty && sortColumn.IndexOf(".") <= 0)
            {
                ParameterExpression[] typeParams = new ParameterExpression[] {
                    Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "")
                };

                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(sortColumn);

                sortColumnDir = sortColumnDir == "asc" ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";

                query = (IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>)query.Provider.CreateQuery(
                    Expression.Call(
                        typeof(Queryable),
                        sortColumnDir,
                        new Type[] { typeof(TEntity), pi.PropertyType },
                        query.Expression,
                        Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(typeParams[0], pi), typeParams))
                );
            }
            else if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }
            else
            {
                query = query.OrderBy(obj => obj.Desativado);
            }

            query = query.Skip(page * pagesize).Take(pagesize);

            return query.ToList();
        }
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What did you try? How do you call your *Get* method?

Comment: This is a good example of why I advocate "just return IQueryable". Abstracting away EF just leads to complex code with quirky issues & edge cases that eat away the hours.

Comment: @AdamSimon I just call like  `ProductRepository.Get( p => p.Name == "X", includeProperties: "Item", sortColumn: "Item.Codigo")`

Answer (score 0):

What does your query builder method do when you pass something like `"X.Y"` in the `sortColumn` parameter?

First it tries

```
if (sortColumn != string.Empty && sortColumn.IndexOf(".") <= 0)
```

The condition evaluates to false as you have a dot in `sortColumn`. So this branch is skipped.

Then comes

```
else if (orderBy != null)
```

This isn't a hit again, you didn't supply the `orderBy` but the `sortColumn` argument.

So finally you end up with

```
else
{
    query = query.OrderBy(obj => obj.Desativado);
}
```

And this is obviously far from what you wanted to achieve as it won't sort by `X.Y` at all.

What to do then? You have to options:

1. You define sorting using callback instead of a path string:

   ```
   ProductRepository.Get(p => p.Name == "X", includeProperties: "Item", orderBy: query => query.OrderBy(product => product.Item.Codigo))
   ```
2. You change the query builder method so that it accepts a property path in `sortColumn`. This would need somewhat more effort, though.